# Find the local.xml file?

Tags: layout

Where can I exactly find the local.xml file to edit the layout of the search results page of the theme? I went through the theme folder but I couldn't find it.

Comment: And further to the correct answers here already, when any documentation refers to modifying something in the local.xml, it could just be referring to any .xml file in the theme layout directory essentially.

Comment: @geoff No, there's an important difference. The local.xml is the last file in the merge process, overriding whatever came before. Secondly it is never distributed by magento or extensions and as such you will not loose its content when upgrading. This is exactly why documentation refers to local.xml.

Answer (score 9):

If the `local.xml` file is not there just create it. It should be in the same place as all other layout files. `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout`.

Comment: #Marius:can you please explain why need "local.xml" file for the theme?

Comment: @H_Parekh you don't need it. But you can use it to override anything else you have in your parent theme. The `local.xml` layout file is loaded after all the other layout files.

Answer (score 6):

The local.xml file does not exist by default. You will have to create it in the package and theme of your choice. It should be placed in the `layout` folder of that theme.